# Grouping the top 2 column maximum value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, etl

I am trying to group my dataset into years which has the highest overall review. But when I tried using groupby nlargest, it is returning only year and review overall score.

For example:

```
style | year | review_score
a     | 1990 | 4.0
b     | 1990 | 5.0
c     | 1990 | 4.2
```

My output should be

```
style | year | review_score
b     | 1990 | 5.0
c     | 1990 | 4.2
```

I tried the below approach:

```
v=style.groupby(by='review_year')['beer_style']['review_overall'].nlargest(3)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) of all columns which need keep first:

```
v = style.set_index('style').groupby(by='year')['review_score'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
print (v)
   year style  review_score
0  1990     b           5.0
1  1990     c           4.2
```

And alternative is sorting first by both columns with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and call [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
v = (style.sort_values(['year','review_score'], ascending=(True, False))
          .groupby(by='year').head(2))
print (v)
  style  year  review_score
1     b  1990           5.0
2     c  1990           4.2
```

Comment: That was awesome. Thank  you